# How to include screenshot function without rooting phone?

Tags: android, image, screenshot, root

I am new to android function and library capabilities thus I'm asking if is there any other way to include a screenshot feature in my app without rooting my phone?

Almost all of the articles I read here only leads to rooting the phone inorder to apply the screenshot function. However, I put one of the code answers in those articles and just returned a black image since my phone is not rooted. I guess.

Is there any other way or shall I start rooting my phone now?

Comment: Do you just want screenshots of your app, or do you want to take screenshots anywhere?

Comment: Just screenshot inside my app @MikeM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a library or root to get screenshots of your own app, since the app has access to all of its own `View`s. We simply need to get the `Activity`'s `DecorView`, and draw it to a `Bitmap` via a `Canvas`. The following method includes a `boolean` `cropStatusBar` parameter to accommodate immersive mode captures.

```
public static Bitmap getActivityScreenshot(Activity activity, boolean cropStatusBar) {
    int statusBarHeight = 0;

    if (cropStatusBar) {
        int resId = activity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
        statusBarHeight = activity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resId);
    }

    View decor = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(decor.getWidth(),
                                        decor.getHeight() - statusBarHeight,
                                        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(result);

    decor.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    Bitmap bmp = decor.getDrawingCache();
    Rect src = new Rect(0, statusBarHeight, bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight());
    Rect dst = new Rect(0, 0, result.getWidth(), result.getHeight());
    c.drawBitmap(bmp, src, dst, null);
    decor.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Ohh I see. Thanks! May I ask what is the initial value of cropStatusBar and where does the cropStatusBar be updated? Also, what are parameters of resId's getIdentifier?